# Insurance that covers the original price of the bike

Tags: cyclocross, theft, bike-vs-car

I'm a new cyclist and new to this forum; hi!
**I forgot to mention I live in the UK.**

I am going to get a cyclocross bike from Evans for just less than £1000 and accessories. I'm mostly concerned about my bike here though. {Though if accessories can also get covered, then great!}

I spoke to the Evans guy instore and he said their insurance likely (he wasn't too sure) covers the price of the bike when it gets stolen and not the original price. As I understand, this is exactly how car insurance works as well. Others I have spoken to have said the same, that this is the norm. And Halfords unfortunately don't even offer any kind of insurance. At least that was what the employee instore said.

So I pay £1000 now and 1 year later, if it gets stolen and I pass all their rigorous checks to prove I'm not ripping them off and it was actually stolen, they will insure the price of the bike as it is when it gets stolen. This is disappointing to say the least. I would at least hope they'd offer price-matching gift cards for a new bike. This is how I'd expect insurance to work. Is this unreasonable? (Not a rhetorical question).

Does anyone know if I can get a price-matching insurance from a third party? Is this even offered anywhere? If not, why not? I'd hope with the high crime rates insurance policies would be more considerate of cyclists' wallets. I don't want to get £400 for a new bike if it ends up getting stolen. You can't even get an average cyclocross for that much, maybe a really low quality one. Plus, this kind of policy would just deter others from becoming cyclists. Maybe unless security was to improve but that's a different issue.

Can someone please shed some light on this?

Comment: AFAIK, most cyclists in the US would just use homeowner/renter's insurance if needed or just deal with it. Learn to lock your bike up properly and lock it up securely and people aren't going to steal your bike.

Comment: @Batman 1) Forgot to add, I live in the UK. Doesn't home insurance only apply to property that is stolen from within your property? So a stolen bike from the town centre would not be covered? 2) I can definitely get used to properly locking the bike. Also, buying quality locks and an alarm just for safe measure, I have no problem with. But having read up the nature of bike thefts recently, I can't help but feel insecure. Not to mention how easy locks are to break through.

Comment: I doubt your proposed insurance scheme would work without an insane premium. As for someone breaking a lock, it isn't that easy with a good quality lock used properly.

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se]. This question is asking for a product recommendation, which has very limited geographic value and little long term value: it will go out of date quickly. We recommend that new members take the [tour] to make best use of the site.

Comment: Sounds like a nice bike.  I'd never let it out of my sight on a ride.  Consider a boring, used rigid MTB as a commuter and all-day park-up instead.

Comment: All your thinking is about your bike being stolen. With this approach you can be sure that it *will* be stolen. Change your thinking: work on keeping it safe!

Comment: What you are wanting is known as a "replacement value" policy, they exist for reasonable rates.

Comment: The problem for the Insurance companies is it encourages fraudulent claims when people decide the want  a new bike theirs suddenly gets stolen, This puts up the cost (paid claims and investigation of claims), which the pass on to policy holders. The higher premium encourages more fraud......  and teh cycle (pun intended) continues

Comment: You can often get a bike put on your home contents insurance, even for when it's not at home. But it might not be cost effective, and the small print can be problematic. There are also standalone bike insurance policies, which are likely to be more suitable than a bike shop would sell you. I'm sure one of the major bikes magazines in the UK must have a recent article.

Comment: A friend in Cambridge who had his insured bike stolen summarised it this way: you don't buy insurance but credit towards a new purchase - i.e. the money you pay for insurance equals the price of the bike. He also found that the company had very strict regulations where and how you could buy the replacement bike. He canceled the insurance. Just an anecdote.

Comment: " Doesn't home insurance only apply to property that is stolen from within your property?" No. Most household contents insurance policies in the UK also cover your stuff when it's not at home. However, there's usually a limit on the amount that any individual item or collection of closely related items is covered for, and your £1000 bike probably goes beyond that limit.

Comment: I just Googled "bicycle insurance", within a couple of seconds I found a company offering new for old replacement in the first 2-3 years, depending on how you pay. Somewhere like money.co.uk would be a good place to start.

Comment: @DavidRicherby you can normally get single high value items included by specifying them when you take out the policy. How much extra it costs is another matter. My bike and my camera kit (similar value) both *could* be covered on this basis but the combination of cost and restrictions means I choose not to.

Comment: @KeithWM What is 'new for old'?

Comment: @KeithWM  It will vary based on location, but here in New Zealand "new for old" is pro-rated/depreciated against the age of the item.   My glasses were "new for old" and I was only paid 33% of the cost of a new pair, before the excess was subtracted.   And insurance wouldn't cover the eye test.

Comment: New for old means if your bike is stolen within the first 2 years for example, you would get the value of a new bike rather than the value of a 2 year old bike. As @Criggie mentioned though there may be other costs and you may need to pay an excess (some % of the cost). Plus - once you make a claim the premium you pay often goes up next year.

Comment: £1000 isn't actually all that much in bike terms (though it's more than I've spent on all the bikes I own added together), and it will depreciate fast, with new models having better features.Security (for which we have lots of questions) and, as you're in the UK, [bikeregister](https://www.bikeregister.com/), including obvious property marking, are more important. I'm not saying don't insure, but it's not going to make everything perfect (and in fact the security and registration might be prerequisites of the policy).